# Remote desktop with TeamViewer, a connection could not be established

Tags: ssh, remote-desktop, teamviewer

I'm trying (for the first time so it could be something obvious) to connect to a remote ubuntu desktop that I have just purchased on a dedicated server. I'm trying to connect to it from an ubuntu OS on my laptop.

I can connect using SSH via secure shell programme no problem and can move around the OS at a command-line level. I can also ping the server IP without any packetloss and low latency.

When trying to connect with a GUI tool such as TeamViewer and I've also tried Remmina it simply won't connect.

TeamViewer gives me the following error: "A connection could not be established. Reason Unknown."

So as you can see this really doesn't help me in anyway to why it can't connect.

Comment: Is teamviewer also on the machine you are trying to connect to?

Answer (score 1):

TeamViewer? Open 80, 443 and 5938-5939 port.

[Which ports are used by TeamViewer?](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/help/334-Which-ports-are-used-by-TeamViewer.aspx)

> In general, TeamViewer will always work if surfing on the Internet is
>   possible. Hence, no firewall configuration is required. As an
>   alternative to port 80 HTTP, port 443 HTTPs is also being checked. In
>   addition, it is also possible to open only port 5938 TCP on the
>   outgoing side. Data traffic should then be able to pass through on
>   this port without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

I believe under advanced options, "deny local connections" is checked by default. If you are ssh'ing in, that would stop you.